# How does Burp update XSS/vulnerability scanning rules/payloads?

Tags: burp-suite, updates, scan

The first point, that it updates with new release. So if somebody discovered new payload for popular frameworks, it will be in burp only with new release. Does Burp app load payloads from Internet sources?

P.S. Except plugins =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their official document "[Updates Settings](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/enterprise/reference/settings/updates)", it states that:”New scans that start after the update will use the updated version of Burp Scanner. It is generally desirable to enable automatic updates of Burp Scanner to ensure that the latest scan checks are available.".  So it means you must update the Burp Scanner with the updated version for the latest scan checks.